# JAR file errors while trying to create an sms java application

Tags: java, eclipse, http, sms

I am trying to create an sms based java application. I am using the Twilio API and have generated some code to create the application. The code is working fine but i am getting jar file errors. I have installed necessary jar file i need but each time i run the app i am requiring a new jar file. The issue lies with the http request.

```java
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.converter.Promoter;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
import org.apache.http.conn.util.*;
import com.twilio.http.*;



public class SENDSMS {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "Your account sid";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "Your auth token";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("num"),
            new PhoneNumber("num"), 
            "Hi").create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
      }
    }
```

I keep getting this error below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ProtocolVersion
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:102)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:129)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
    at SENDSMS.main(SENDSMS.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Below are the following jar files i have added to my builpath in the lib folder.

```
apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar
google-collect-1.0.jar
guava.jar
httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar
org-apache-commons-logging.jar
twilio-7.21.5.jar
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

httpcore-4.1.1.jar is missing.

You should seriously consider using a build tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). Both are very well tested and will save you lots of time when it comes to dependency management.